# Quarto Website - How to insert a link with a literal path?

Tags: r-markdown, quarto, static-site

Our Quarto site is served from a subdirectory on the host machine.

[www.example.com/qsite/](http://www.example.com/qsite/)

The option `site-url` is properly set in the `_quarto.yml`. We've tried changing the `site-path` too.

We'd like to include links to other paths on the host machine, e.g. to `/`, `/static`, `/shiny`, but Quarto seems to modify all relative links. For example, a link to `/` in `index.qmd` is translated to `./` in the generated `index.html`.

We could include the full URL `https://www.example.com/` but would like to avoid this if possible. Is there a way to work around this and get Quarto to use the relative link as-is?

Comment: `../other_directory` which translates to `www.example.com/other_directory` should work.